# Several for loops in batch script do not work

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have simple script:

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%

for /d %%i in (dir1\*) do (
    cd %%i
    ant clean compile deploy
    cd %cd%
)

for /d %%i in (dir2\*) do (
    cd %%i
    ant clean compile deploy
    cd %cd%
)
```

that should run *some command* in every subfolder of dir1 and dir2. But:

1. When I run the script only the first for loop is executed. How to make second loop also run?
2. Additionally @echo off seems to work only for first iteration of the loop, and every other displays:

   C:*\Desktop>(
   cd dir1\folder
    *some command*
    cd C:*\Desktop\
   )

Comment: The script works OK for me. What exactly the `some command` is? The `echo %%i` works OK.

Comment: As Dmitry stated, the error **must** be cause by `*some command*`. Please give us the code!

Comment: Also, rather than storing the current directory as `%back%`, use `pushd` and `popd`.  You should also quote your paths in case they contain spaces or ampersands or other batch script road hazards.  Examples: `set "back=%cd%"` and `cd "%%~i"`

Comment: You are right it works fine with other commands, but when I use "ant clean compile deploy" it stops after first folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestions above your code should look like this.

```
@echo off

for /d %%i in (dir1\*) do (
    pushd "%%~i"
    call ant clean compile deploy
    popd
)

for /d %%i in (dir2\*) do (
    pushd "%%~i"
    call ant clean compile deploy
    popd
)
```

Comment: doesn't pushd "%%~i" store directory dir1\somefolder\ ? if I need to go back to dir1\ shouldn't I use pushd dir1 ?

Comment: well it works how it should, but I would have to read some more about these commands, thanks for help

Comment: @pierdut, the POPD makes it go back to the previous directory in the stack.

Comment: but why pushd "%%~i"? Isn't this some "deeper" directory, a folder in dir1 or dir2? So why popd changes directory to the folder where script is located?

Comment: @pierdut, turn ECHO ON and put some pauses in there and watch it execute.  You don't even need your ANT command in there.